# Finding the sum of a curry function?

Tags: javascript

```
var curry = function (func) {
    return function (a) {
        return function (b) {
            return function (c) {
                return function (d) {
                    return function (e) {
                        return func (a, b, c, d, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var getSum=curry(a+b+c+d+e);
console.log(getSum(15)(20)(25)(30)(35));
```

This is my code so far, but it's saying a is not defined and I'm not sure how to fix it. If I do this with Math.max it works, how can I achieve the same thing but with a sum instead of max?

Comment: That's because on this line `var getSum=curry(a+b+c+d+e);`, `a` is nowhere defined. same with `b`, `c`, `d`, & `e`

Comment: But I defined them in the line below that, it worked when I used Math.max instead of getting the sum, that's why I'm confused. How should I be defining it instead?

Comment: Check the answers now

Answer (score 2):

By defining a function that sums its arguments, just like `Math.max` finds the max of its arguments:

```js
const curry = function (func) {
    return function (a) {
        return function (b) {
            return function (c) {
                return function (d) {
                    return function (e) {
                        return func (a, b, c, d, e);
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

const getSum = (...args) => {
    return args.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
};

console.log(curry(getSum)(15)(20)(25)(30)(35));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a function for the five parameters and take the function for the first call of `curry`.

```js
var curry = function(func) {
  return function(a) {
    return function(b) {
      return function(c) {
        return function(d) {
          return function(e) {
            return func(a, b, c, d, e);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var getSum = function (a, b, c, d, e) { return a + b + c + d + e; };

console.log(curry(getSum)(15)(20)(25)(30)(35));
```

A dynamic approach without binding.

```js
var curry = fn => {
        const
            curried = p => (...args) => {
                p = [...p, ...args];
                return p.length < fn.length
                    ? curried(p)
                    : fn(...p);
            };

        return curried([]);
    },
    getSum = (a, b, c, d, e) => a + b + c + d + e;

console.log(curry(getSum)(15)(20)(25)(30)(35));

var add = curry((a, b, c, d) => a + b + c + d),
    add1 = add(1),
    add2 = add(2)(3)(4);

console.log(add1() === 10); // false
```

Comment: this is instance based and without individual binding does not follow the definition of a curried function. If I call this function, it pushes onto the parameters array, meaning individual calls are not curried, they are the same instance *as all earlier calls* with *the same parameters* that grow to infinity. I cannot do `const add2 = curry(add)(2); const add5 = add2(3); const add4 = add2(2)` with this version as `add2`, `add5`, and `add4` all now have the same internal parameter array of `[2, 3, 2]`.

Comment: example of the problem: `var add = curry((a,b,c,d) => a+b+c+d); var add1 = add(1);` current state: `parameters = [1]`. `var add2 = add(2)(3)(4)` `add2 == 10`. `add1() === 10 // true`

Comment: @RobertMennell, ow it should work. please see edit.

Comment: by using a lamda function you introduce an internal scope and essentially a bunch of bound scopes every run anyways. You could just use a full form function and bind to shorten the code. No matter what wit Curry you still bind, so if you remove that note I think I'm out of things that would cause me to downvote

Answer (score 1):

Curry is expecting a function with your decleration

```js
var curry = function (func) {...}
```

You should be calling it with a function. However you're attempting to resolving some variables and add them then just pass the number. What you have here is a `Higher Order Function`, or a Function which takes a Function and returns a Function.

```js
var getSum=curry(a+b+c+d+e); // not passing a function
```

Your code however is attempting to do the following:

```js
var temp = a+b+c+d+e;
var getSum=curry(temp);
```

The problem is that now it's attempting to find a global `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` variable, to sum them, and then pass that to `curry`... which fails as soon as it tries to find a global `a`. What you want to pass is a function.

```js
var getSum = curry((...arg) => args.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value));
```

This is a function that takes a variable amount of arguments, so when you pass it to curry it will return a function(`a` internal to curry scope), which when called will return a function(`b` to `a` scope) which will return a fun.... so on and so forth until it finally calls the last time and sums them all after the last call.

Another more advanced version of an automatic curry function with examples from [30 Seconds of Code](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/)

```js
const curry = (fn, arity = fn.length, ...args) =>
  arity <= args.length ? fn(...args) : curry.bind(null, fn, arity, ...args);

curry(Math.pow)(2)(10); // 1024
curry(Math.min, 3)(10)(50)(2); // 2
```

Other versions of Curry exist in other places like [RamdaJS](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry), but you get the idea. It's a higher order function that continuously returns functions until you've supplied enough arguments to satisfy it's arity(how many arguments it wants).

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic approach for `curry` function. Here What I have done is `curry` function takes the function to be curried `func` returns a new function `temp`.

Inside `temp` we check if length of arguments of temp is less than the number of arguments required for the  original function `func`.

If it is less we return temp again with the arguments received, else call the original function `func` with all the arguments

```js
var getSum = function (a, b, c, d, e) { return a + b + c + d + e; };
function curry(func){
    return function temp(...args) {
        if (args.length < func.length) {
             return temp.bind(null, ...args)
        }
        return func(...args)
    }
}

console.log(curry(getSum)(15)(20)(25)(30)(35));
```

Comment: you don't need an internal function. Just take a function and collect the rest into args. Then if args is less than func.length, return a bound instance of curry.

Comment: Can you please help me with one small example?

Comment: `return curry.bind(undefined, func, ...args)`